# Exponential of a self-adjoint operator

Tags: hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory, adjoint-operators, functional-calculus

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be an Hilbert space.

---

### Firstly, I shall define some notions as their definitions may vary:

A **spectral resolution** is a function $E:\mathbb{R}\to\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ (the space of continuous operators from and to $\mathcal{H}$) iff the following holds:

1. $E(t)$ is an orthogonal projection for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$
2. $\text{Im}(E(s))\subset\text{Im}(E(t))\forall s<t$, which is denoted by $E(s)<E(t)$
3. $\lim_{s>0,s\to 0}E(t+s)=E(t)$ (right continuity), i.e. $\cap_{s>t}\text{Im}(E(s))=\text{Im}(E(t))$
4. $\lim_{t\to -\infty}E(t)x=0$ and $\lim_{t\to\infty}E(t)x=x$ for all $x\in\mathcal{H}$

Define $E(t^{-}):=\lim_{\epsilon>0,\epsilon\to 0}E(t-\epsilon)$. It can be seen as the orthogonal projection onto $\cup_{s<t}\text{Im}(E(s))$.

As $s\mapsto (E(s)f,f)$ is positive, increasing and right-continuous for any fixed $f\in\mathcal{H}$, we can define the following Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral ($\varphi$ measurable and bounded):

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi(s)\text{d}(E(s)f,f)$$

This naturaly defines a space $L^{2}(\mathbb{R},(E(\cdot)f,f))$. Now, we define

$$\begin{align*}
E[a,b]&=E(b)-E(a^{-})\\
E(a,b)&=E(b^{-})-E(a)\\
E[a,b)&=E(b^{-})-E(a^{-})\\
E(a,b]&=E(b)-E(a)
\end{align*}$$

Let $\phi=\sum_{i=1}^{m}c_{i}\mathbb{I}(I_{i})$ where $I_{i}$ is a real interval (i.e. let $\phi$ be a simple function) and where $I_{i}\cap I_{j}=\emptyset$ for all $i\neq j$. We define:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(s)\text{d}E(s):=\sum_{i=1}^{m}c_{i}E(I_{i})$$

(this integral is an operator, not a scalar).

Now, for any $\varphi\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R},(E(\cdot)f,f))$, the following is well-defined:

$$\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\varphi(s)\text{d}E(s)\right)f=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi_{n}(s)\text{d}(E(s)f,f)$$

where $\phi_{n}$ are simple functions and

$$\phi_{n}\overset{L^{2}(\mathbb{R},(E(\cdot)f,f))}{\longrightarrow}\varphi$$

A version of the **spectral theorem** may be expressed as follows: for any self-adjoint operator $T$ over $\mathcal{H}$, there exists a spectral resolution $E_{T}$ such that

$$T=\int_{\mathbb{R}}s\text{d}E(s)$$

and the domain of $T$ can be expressed as $D(T)=\left\{f\in\mathcal{H}\mid\int_{\mathbb{R}}s^{2}\text{d}(E(s)f,f)<\infty\right\}$

Now, if $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ is measurable, bounded over the spectrum $\sigma(T)$ of $T$, we define

$$\varphi(T):=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi(s)\text{d}E(s)$$

and we have the following properties:

1. $\varphi(T)$ is bounded;
2. $\varphi(T)+\psi(T)=(\varphi+\psi)(T)$;
3. $\varphi(T)\circ\psi(T)=(\varphi\psi)(T)$;
4. $\varphi(T)^{\ast}=\bar{\varphi}(T)$ where $U^{\ast}$ denotes the adjoint of $U$ for any operator $U$ and $\bar{\varphi}:s\mapsto \overline{\varphi(s)}$ maps $s$ to the complex conjugate of $\varphi(s)$;
5. Moreover, if $\varphi$ is continuous, $\varphi(\sigma(T))=\sigma(\varphi(T))$.

---

### Now comes my question:

We know that $s\mapsto e^{-its}$ ($t\in\mathbb{R}$) is a bounded, measurable function, so that $e^{-itU}$ is a well-defined operator for any self-adjoint operator $U$. We want to prove that if $f_{0}$ is an eigenvector of $U$ with associated eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $f_{0}$ is an eigenvector of $e^{-itU}$ with eigenvalue $e^{-it\lambda}$. From the properties mentioned above, it is clear that $e^{-it\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue. However, how can I prove that $f_{0}$ is an eigenvector?

As $e^{-itU}$ is bounded, I am tempted to say that

$$e^{-itU}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-it)^{n}U^{n}}{n!}$$

but I am not sure how to prove this. If this is true, we can easily deduce that $e^{-it\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue (which we already know) associated with the eigenvector $f_{0}$.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvector $f_0$ is in the range of the spectral projection $E_[\lambda, \lambda] = E(\lambda) - E(\lambda^-)$, while
$E(\lambda^-) f_0 = 0$ and $(E(x) - E(\lambda)) f_0 = 0$ for $x > \lambda$.  Thus for any $f \in \mathcal H$, the measure
$\langle f, dE(s)\; f_0 \rangle = d \langle f, E(s) f_0\rangle$ is a point mass of $\langle f, f_0\rangle$ at $s=\lambda$ 
and
$$ \langle f, \phi(T) f_0 \rangle = \int_{\mathbb R} \phi(s) \;\langle f,  dE(s) f_0 \rangle = \phi(\lambda) \langle f, f_0 \rangle = \langle f, \phi(\lambda) f_0 \rangle$$
which implies
$\phi(T) f_0 = \phi(\lambda) f_0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't get $(f,\text{d}E(s)f_{0})$: how is that defined? I mean that $(f,\text{d}E(s)f_{0})$ may be negative. How can we construct a measure with this? (I have heard of non-positive measures but my course is only considering positive ones, so that it is difficult for me to entirely understand your answer).